# Unit Test Spring Boot with Controller -> Service -> Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to apply unit tests in spring boot using controller, service, and repository (SPRING DATA), however when I tried to execute the tests, and show this message for me.

> Field parameterRepository in ParameterService required a bean of type ParameterRepository that could not be found.

I put @repository in my interface repository, however does not work.

I am attaching the parts of code to your help.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ParameterController.class, secure = false)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ParameterController.class, ParameterService.class, ParameterRepository.class})
public class ParameterTest {

@Autowired
private WebTestClient webClient;

@Test
public void getParamterById() {
    this.webClient.get().uri("/parameters/v1").exchange().expectStatus().isOk();
}
```

}

```
public interface ParameterRepository  extends MongoRepository<Parameter, ObjectId>{

Optional<Parameter> findByCode(String code);
```

}

Somebody knows how to resolve this problem with test in Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@ContextConfiguration` isn't pointing to your `@Configutation` classes. You don't need to pass your controller and service classes to ContextConfiguration.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ParameterController.class, ParameterService.class, ParameterRepository.class})
```

---

You can have a separate class @TestConfiguration which will by-default scan and load all the classes in the current and children packages.

```
@TestConfiguration
public class MyTestConfiguration {
```

Pass this test configuration class to your `@ContextConfiguration`

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MyTestConfiguration.class})
```

---

If you Test Configuration is not on the top of package hierarchy
you can use `@ComponentScan` like this

```
@ComponentScan({"com.my.package.first","com.my.package.second"})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help